# Keeping video aspect ratio using max 100% for both width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I want to integrate a youtube video using their embed code in a "pop-up".

My problem is that the video doesn't constraint to the height of its parent. I want it not to go higher than the div#pop-up containing the video. Right now it will go as wide as possible and keep its aspect ratio on the height even if it exeed the parents height. What I want is for the video to go as big as possible within the parents padding or margin, keep it centered and keep its aspect ration (16:9).

I don't want to use jQuery, javascript might be an option.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#pop-up{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  padding:5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up">
  <!--Youtube embed code-->
  <div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZLtNZuQzJ4w?ecver=2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of what I want visualy:

With a wide browser like a computer or landscape phone:
[image: With a wide browser like a computer or landscape phone:]

With a tall browser like a portrait phone or tablet:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution here is to use media queries to monitor the windows aspect ratio, since my pop up covers the whole windows size in the first place. Then I had to use an image that has the right aspect ratio (16px x 9px) at 100% height to exploit the capacity browsers have to keep the width of the image to the right ratio to its height. Using an inline-block to then capture the image size and a position absolute top 0 right 0 bottom 0 left 0 trick to apply the size of the parent to the video container.

This would all work fine is width auto refreshed on the resize of its child element or on the resize of the window, so i used a verry simple javascript line simply removing and re-applying the  width auto after you're done resizing.

I've given up on the centered video idea and I will instead use the space left to apply some more content.

```js
var rtime;
var timeout = false;
var delta = 200;
window.onresize = function(){
    rtime = new Date();
    if (timeout === false) {
        timeout = true;
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    }
};

function resizeend() {
    if (new Date() - rtime < delta) {
        setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
    } else {
        timeout = false;
        if(window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight>16/10){
          document.getElementById("videoWrapper").style.width="0";
          setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("videoWrapper").style.width="auto";
          },100)
        }
    }               
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#pop-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
}
#videoWrapper {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
  width:100%;
}
@media all and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/10) { 
  #videoWrapper {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
  }
  #videoWrapper img{
    height:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up">
  <div id="videoWrapper">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZLtNZuQzJ4w?ecver=2"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0"></iframe>
    <img src="http://jaunemoutarde.ca/denique/4/images/16x9_aspect_ratio.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a couple of changes to your styling.

See if this works for you, please.

As you can see below, it's the way you asked to be:

[image]

[image]

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  body #pop-up iframe {
    max-height: 34.6vh;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#pop-up {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#pop-up iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  max-height: 576px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop-up">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZLtNZuQzJ4w?ecver=2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the images i used as examples in my question, you'll see what I mean. Right now it will strech the player and make eighter black bars on each sides of the video or on top and bottom. What I want is no black bars so the iframe should allways be constraint to 16:9 ratio and be as big as possible, in the center of its parent.

Comment: When i answered, you hadn't included the images yet. I'll take a better look as soon as i get home.

Comment: It's really appreciated!

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier, did it work? I had forgotten to set absolute position to the parent.

Comment: It's weird it desn't look like yout pictures on my end. I thnink its because I use the meta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: You're right. When i added this meta to my test html file, it affected the video ratio.

Comment: It's because your snippet on stackoverflow will resize on the "mobile" mode of chrome. I copied your snippet on codepen to illustrate, they use that meta. [Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/scharpentier0/full/pPmbmZ/)

Comment: I think it might be impossible using only css

Comment: Maybe using media querries using the landscape/portrait settings, I'll have to look into that on monday.

Comment: @SamuelCharpentier, i was trying to avoid media queries, but it seems that there's no escape. Lol. I have updated the answer again. See if it works out.